# Why does this constructor that uses generics fail?

Tags: java, generics, constructor, generic-list, generic-programming

I am creating a class that, at present, stores lists of various types in an internal object called `genericTable`. Each list (composed of either `Double`, or `Long`) are all held in an object which is an instance of class `GenericList`.

**Question: Why doesn't the method `addVector` work?**

The error under the red underline says `the constructor Test<V>.GenericList<V>(List<List<V>>) is undefined`.

If I was working in a `main` method (but had the same `GenericList` class) and created `genericTable` within the main method (using `List<GenericList<?>> Table = new ArrayList<GenericList<?>>();`) and did `genericTable.add(new GenericList<Long>(Arrays.asList(genericVector)));` (where `genericVector` in this case is a `List<Long>`), it works perfectly.

```
public class Test<V> {

    private final List<GenericList<?>> genericTable = new ArrayList<GenericList<?>>();

    public void addVector(List<V> genericVector) {
        genericTable.add(new GenericList<V>(Arrays.asList(genericVector)));
    }

    private class GenericList<K> {
        private final List<K> listGeneric;    

        public GenericList(List<K> input) {
           listGeneric = input;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use Java naming conventions. It is very hard to work out what is a `class` and what is a variable when everything starts with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 4):

You're unnecessarily using Arrays.asList(), when you already have a list. Consequently you get a list of lists, which is not what the constructr accepts.

See this from the javadocs:

> This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size list
>   initialized to contain several elements:
>
> ```
>  List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
> ```

So in your case you're getting a list of lists, instead of a list of strings.

I've added this bit from the comments, for clarity:

The method signature for asList() is like this:-

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

So because T... a is a vararg, when you pass in "Larry", "Moe", "Curly", the compiled method actually receives an array of `["Larry", "Moe", "Curly"]`, and returns them as a List.

So because you passed in a List, rather than an array, the method takes the vararg array like this: [genericVector], and returns that array as a list, and you constructor breaks.

Comment: So all is fine and dandy if I just change the suspect method to `genericTable.add(new GenericList<V>(genericVector));`? This does seem to work.

Comment: @user2763361 I can't run your entire code, but that line was definitely wrong, and the cause of the error you asked about. Your constructor wants a list, and you already had a list, so you should be fine just squirting that list in, rather than using Arrays.asList().

Comment: @user2763361 Normally Arrays.asList() is used to turn an Array into a list. As the snippet i posted shows, you can also use it to get a list from a sequence of individual objects.

Comment: @user2763361 Sorry... forgot to add:   the second use I mentioned works because varArgs used in a method invocation actually are represented by an array under the hood. So Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly"); is the same as String[] anArray = {"larry", "Moe", "Curly"}; Arrays.asList(anArray);